# Term for the smaller words to be ignored in a textual analysis

Tags: generic-term

I am using a text analysis tool to analyse a number of academic texts. The tool provides a list of words used, and a count for each. When describing the results, I want to distinguish between the meaningful/significant words, and the rest - which are generic words such as 'the', 'and', 'a', 'of', 'to', 'is', 'in', 'that', 'for', 'be' etc.

I need a word or phrase that can best describe these generic words, so that I can say that I have eliminated them from my review.  My sentence as it stands is:

> ‘Risk’ was the third most frequently used word, after eliminating the *generic* words from the analysis.

I am looking to replace *generic* in this sentence with the correct term.

Comment: I don't think 'generic' is an appropriate term: have you looked it up in a dictionary?  What's wrong with "common words" or "commonly used words"?  In either case, you perhaps need to specify what you are referring to as 'common words': you mention only a few, but are words such as "that", "which", "do", etc. included in that scope.

Comment: @TrevorD - thanks. I've added more examples of these common words, and noted that generic is the word I am trying to replace - I agree it's not a good fit here. Perhaps it's easier to define the opposite, i.e. the significant/meaningful words - which appear to be mostly nouns and adjectives (examples: "disaster", "management", "emergency", "vulnerability", "social")

Comment: Up to you which way you define them, but I imagine that your program has a list of words to be *ignored*, rather than a list of words to be included (otherwise you may omit to count unusual words).  So I think you're right to refer to the *excluded* words, and I would stick with 'common', maybe 'insignificant'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [support.dtsearch](https://support.dtsearch.com/webhelp/dtsearch/default.htm#noise_words.htm)...

> *A **noise word** is a word such as **the** or **if** that is so common that it is not useful in searches. To save time, noise words are not indexed and are ignored in index searches.*

But it's also worth noting [this from Microsoft...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551.aspx)

> *SQL Server has a mechanism that discards commonly occurring strings that do not help the search. These discarded strings are called **stopwords***.

Comment: thanks. I'm going to go with 'noise words' because I feel the meaning would be more self evident to my audience than 'stopwords' would be. Cheers!

Comment: I named ***noise word*** first because that's the "non-specialist" term I normally use myself, and I assume it's more easily understood by ordinary people. I'm familiar with the computer indexing context, but to me ***stopword*** is effectively "domain-specific jargon". But noting Wikipedia's [Words that are not function words are called content words (or open class words or lexical words or autosemantic words)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word) I don't understand why Almu's answer was downvoted & then deleted - ***function word*** is just another domain-specific (grammar) term.